# PHP - Separate tags with span tags from database

Tags: php, tags

I am creating a website that will have some places and for each place I want to have tags. I have a database with a table name checkbox and inside the table I have a column called checkbox_title. In my backend I have three checkboxes which have the values basketball, baseball, and volleyball. If I check all or some of the boxes I would like to add them to the database, inside checkbox_title column. I have done this using implode(). However, when I insert them in my database there are separated with a comma, which is fine but in the front end of my website I would like to show the tags as separated wrapped in a span tag, not as a group using span tag. What I would like is to know if there is a way to separated implode() values using span tags instead of comma. Hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

PS. I have added comments in my front end to understand how I want this to work.

Backend Code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">

       <?php
            if(isset($_POST['add_tags'])) {

                $tags = implode(', ' , $_POST['tags']);
                $query = "INSERT INTO checkbox (checkbox_title) VALUES ('$tags') ";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                if(!$result) {
                    die("Error ".mysqli_error($connection));
                }

            }
        ?>

        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="basketball">Basketball</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="baseball">Baseball</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="volleyball">Volleyball</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="add_tags" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </div>

</form>
```

Front end code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <?php
            $select_all_query = "SELECT * FROM checkbox";
            $select_all_query_con = mysqli_query($connection, $select_all_query);
            while($tags = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_query_con)) {

                $product_tags = $tags['checkbox_title'];
                echo "<span class='c_span'>$product_tags</span>";
            }

        ?>
<!--
        <span class="c_span">Basketball</span>
        <span class="c_span">Baseball</span>
        <span class="c_span">Volleyball</span>

-->
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Save each tag into new row in database, not as one string separated by commas... You can use `explode`, but it's wrong approach.

Comment: If you have 3 database columns (baseball, basketball, volleyball) why would you not create 3 different $_POST variables with the same names? Then you can check which ones have been set and set those records to the database...

Comment: @FrankW. wrong approach. Adding a new tag can't be a task to alter table (add a new column in there). In HTML/PHP app, using array is good-practice, instead of your multiple variables.

Comment: Thanks all for ur help. Aiyaz Khorajia code is the one I was looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update front code as bellow

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <?php
            $select_all_query = "SELECT * FROM checkbox";
            $select_all_query_con = mysqli_query($connection, $select_all_query);
            while($tags = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_query_con)) {

                $product_tags = $tags['checkbox_title'];
                $tags =  explode(',', $product_tags);

                foreach ($tags as $item) {
                   echo "<span class='c_span'>". $item ."</span>";
                }
            }

        ?>
<!--
        <span class="c_span">Basketball</span>
        <span class="c_span">Baseball</span>
        <span class="c_span">Volleyball</span>

-->
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure, why people do negative rating without even understanding the question.